# How to add , Up navigation in a Fragment?

Tags: android-fragments, fragment, android-jetpack, android-architecture-navigation

Hello friends I have added an  Up navigation in my project and it is reflected in all the fragments, the problem is that I only want it to be reflected in some fragments.
[image]

I want to create exactly the ones indicated in the red circle in the image, but in a fragment

MainActivity

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        val navController = this.findNavController(R.id.nav_host_fragment)
        setupActionBarWithNavController(this,navController) 
    }

    override fun onSupportNavigateUp(): Boolean {
        val navController = this.findNavController(R.id.nav_host_fragment)
        return navController.navigateUp()
    }
}
```

One of the fagments in which I want to add the upward navigation

```
class LogInFragment : Fragment() {
    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?

    ): View? {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_log_in, container, false)
    }
    override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)

        val buttonLogIn = view.findViewById<ImageView>(R.id.imageViewButtonLogIn)
        buttonLogIn.setOnClickListener {
            findNavController().navigate(R.id.action_logInFragment_to_lugaresFragment)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: have you try with nav graph

Comment: I'm working with the navigation component but I don't know how to do it.

Comment: provide some more detail in your question like nav graph and manifest

Comment: added details of my nav_graph (above), regarding the manifest I have not made any changes.

Comment: provide full nav_grpah.xml becausei need to check from which fragment you are coming from this login_in fragment so that i can understand to tell to the proper way to do it

Comment: I have already updated the post.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/223700/discussion-between-jorge-leonardo-and-burhan-khanzada).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a method to hide the Up navigation,  this way we can decide where it can appear.

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        val hideUpButton = AppBarConfiguration(
            setOf(R.id.logInFragment)
        )

        val navController = this.findNavController(R.id.nav_host_fragment)
        setupActionBarWithNavController(this, navController,hideUpButton)

    }

    override fun onSupportNavigateUp(): Boolean {
        val navController = this.findNavController(R.id.nav_host_fragment)
        return navController.navigateUp()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try this in your nav_graph

```
 <activity
    android:id="@+id/mainActivity"
    android:name="com.example.MainActivity"
    android:label="Main Activity"
    tools:layout="@layout/activity_main">
    <action
        android:id="@+id/action_mainActivity_to_loginFragment"
        app:destination="@id/loginFragment" />
</fragment>

 <fragment
    android:id="@+id/loginFragment"
    android:name="com.example.LogInFragment"
    android:label="Login In"
    tools:layout="@layout/fragment_log_in" />
```